# Git alias to grep file for non-comment lines

Tags: bash, git, grep

I am trying to make a git alias to output the contents of `.git/info/exclude`, minus the comments. I'm using:

```
[alias]
excluded = !sh -c 'cat .git/info/exclude | grep -v "#"'
```

but this just returns the grep usage description. The line works fine executed outside of the git alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `!sh -c ...` is a bit redundant as `!` means "run the rest of this through the shell".  The only reason to use `sh -c` here is if "the shell" that your Git chooses is not `sh` and you explicitly need `sh`.

Now, the reason it fails should be more obvious if you do this:

```
[alias]
    test = !sh -c 'echo "pound sign #"'
```

Run this as is, first by itself, then with `GIT_TRACE=1` to show who ate the character, and it produces:

```
$ git test
pound sign
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git test
16:54:54.313367 git.c:702               trace: exec: git-test
16:54:54.314881 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-test
16:54:54.318006 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'sh -c '\''echo pound sign #'\'''
pound sign
```

As you can see, Git itself gave the literal text `'echo pound side #'` as the (single) argument to `sh -c`.  The fault is the shell's: it ate the `#`, as it should, because that's a comment:

```
#! /bin/sh
# everything with # is a comment
echo like this # comment about the echo
```

If you must get the `#` through, you need to quote it from the shell, i.e., prefix it with a backslash `\`.  Of course, to get a backslash through *Git*, you must quote it, i.e., prefix it with a backslash:

```
[alias]
    test = !sh -c 'echo "pound sign \\#"'
```

Applying the same to your own alias (and dropping the `sh -c '...'` part as noted earlier) produces:

```
[alias]
    excluded = !cat .git/info/exclude | grep -v "\\#"
```

which works, but has a UUOC (Useless Use Of Cat):

```
    excluded = !grep -v "\\#" .git/info/exclude
```

suffices.  (There seems to be no way to quote the `#` without using double quotes, and even then we must always protect it from the shell.)